# Oracle IMPDP fail - unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace

Tags: oracle, impdp

I'm trying to import a database dump into our local Oracle 11.2g using the IMPDP functionality, but am getting the following error:

```
ORA-39171: Job is experiencing a resumable wait.
ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace {TABLESPACE}
```

All of the answers/solutions I have seen for this, tell you to ALTER the tablespace with the following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'C:\APP\ADMIN\ORADATA\ORCL\TABLESPACE.DBF' AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
```

I have done this, but am still getting the same error. Any other suggestions as to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error: `unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace {TABLESPACE}'

Check your disk space to have enough space to create an extent of the table

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like recreating the TABLESPACE using this has worked - CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE